# How can I make fields for contacts visible to the owner, but hidden from peers or subordinates in Vtiger CRM?

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

It's possible to set privileges for fields on a per profile basis. This allows me to make a field invisible, read only, or read/write capable for all users under a profile. However, I need the owner of the record to still have access to a field. I only want to hide the field from other users with the same profile.

Answer (score 0):

As per my vtiger experience that not possible which you required but you can make sharing rules to private for contact module so Owner will have access to particular field. If you still want to allow access to record then you must have to customize CRM for that.